# Regex + loop + OR

Tags: regex, perl

I have this kind of regex:

```
$recipes =~ s/

                ([^\.\/]) ($dimentions) (\s) ($unit)
                |(\(?) ($wholeNumberDecimal) (\s) ($unit)   
                |(\(?) ($wholeNumber)       (\s) ($unit)    
                |(\(?) ($wholeNumberFraction) (\s) ($unit)
                /transformer($1,$2,$3,$4) /eixg;
```

What I would like it to do is every time it matches against one of those 4 cases it calls a method.

From my understatement there will be a `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`. If I pass all of those variables to the method then how will the method know which variable is the new match and which ones might have been matched before and are simply being remembered?

Is there a way of having just one variable `$1` that gets matched to any of those cases, and simply send that one to the method anytime?

Or do I even have the right approach? I am trying to match these different cases from a recipe book and with each match call a method that transforms that into the metric system equivalent.

Example: 5 Tbsp -> 80 ml, or 8 x 8 x 2 inches ->20 x 20 x 5 cm

Based on posted answers I have changed my regex to:

```
$recepies =~ s/
                    (?|
                    ([^\.\/]) ($dimentions) 
                    |
                    (\(?) ($wholeNumberDecimal)     #ex: 1.5
                    |
                    (\(?) ($wholeNumber)            #ex: 1
                    |
                    (\(?) ($wholeNumberFraction) 
                    )
                    (\s) ($unit)

                    /transformer($1,$2,$3,$4) /eixg;    #the replacement
```

It seems to be working!

Comment: This might be better done in something like [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [Alternative capture group numbering](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Alternative-capture-group-numbering):

```
$recipes =~ s{
    (?| 
        ( [^\.\/] ) ($dimentions)
        |
        ( \(? ) ($wholeNumberDecimal)
        |
        ( \(? ) ($wholeNumber)
        |
        ( \(? ) ($wholeNumberFraction)
    )
    (\s)
    ($unit)
}{
    transformer($1,$2,$3,$4)
}eixg;
```

Comment: They don't call it branch reset anymore?

Comment: @sln Perl calls it "Alternative capture group numbering", [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) calls it "Duplicate subpattern numbers" and also refers to it as "branch reset". Most tutorials use "branch reset"... I guess you can choose the one you like most :)

Comment: @Mariano - Strange. From the Perl _5.20 perlre_ docs `(?|pattern) 
This is the "branch reset" pattern, which has the special property that the capture groups are numbered from the same starting point in each alternation branch.`

Comment: @Mariano:  "Alternative capture group numbering" is merely the title of that section in the Perl documentation.  The same goes for "Duplicate Subpattern Numbers" in the PCRE docs.  The construct used to achieve it is called "Branch Reset Group" in both flavors; I think that name is the one most likely to be understood.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need but its not working depite my attemps. Also I am  unfamiliar with using curly braces to do the regex. Can you use the traditional notation s///?

Answer (score 1):

`From my understatement there will be a $1, $2, $3, $4. If I pass all of those variables to the method then how will the method know which variable is the new match and which ones might have been matched before and are simply being remember`

I believe these variable's are modified on a successful match.
Given the *sub* form `s///`, there is only one way the Right Hand Side is
accessed. That is on a successful match.
So, it is not the case of it being matched before, the match var's are
always current in this case.

Below is your regex formatted. I suggest getting software that can do this
for you. I used [RegexFormat 7](http://www.regexformat.com).

```
   ( [^\.\/] )                   # (1)
   ( $dimentions )               # (2)
   ( \s )                        # (3)
   ( $unit )                     # (4)
|  
   ( \(? )                       # (5)
   ( $wholeNumberDecimal )       # (6)
   ( \s )                        # (7)
   ( $unit )                     # (8)
|  
   ( \(? )                       # (9)
   ( $wholeNumber )              # (10)
   ( \s )                        # (11)
   ( $unit )                     # (12)
|   
   ( \(? )                       # (13)
   ( $wholeNumberFraction )      # (14)
   ( \s )                        # (15)
   ( $unit )                     # (16)
```

As you can see it contains 16 capture groups.
So, groups 1-4 only cover your first alternative sections.

Regex have to be designed to get the *outcome* you anticipate.
If you only care about which section of 4 alternatives matched,
then you can use the capture variable as a flag as well as getting data.
In Perl, its common to use

```
if ( defined( $1 ) ) {
   ## ..
}
elsif ( defined ( $2 ) {
   ## ...
}  
etc ...
```

After some factoring it could be done like below.
And, if those variables contain literals you should wrap them in a
quotemeta construct like `\Q  $variable \E`

Note also that if the variables contain *constant* data (literals or regex)
they should be pre-compiled at the beginning of your program
like with a quote regex operator `my $regex = qr~...~;`

Then just put it into your normal call like this
`$recipes =~ s/$regex/transformer($1,$2,$3,$4)/eixg;`

Note that I believe Perl might be able to scope its capture vars
somehow, but I'm a little rusty so can't remember.

If you need to pass in the vars, just use something like

```
sub transformer {
   my ($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4) = @_;
   ...
}
```

Below uses the fact that you've designed capture groups as flags
as well.

```
sub transformer
{
    my ($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4) =  @_;

    if ( defined( $v1 ) ) {
        return ...;
    }
    elsif ( defined( $v2 ) ) {
        return ...;
    }
    elsif ( defined( $v3 ) ) {
        return ...;
    }
    elsif ( defined( $v4 ) ) {
        return ...;
    }
}


$recipes =~ s~  

     (?:
          [^./] 
          ( $dimentions )              # (1)
       |  
          \(? 
          (?:
               ( $wholeNumberDecimal )      # (2)
            |  ( $wholeNumber )             # (3)
            |  ( $wholeNumberFraction )     # (4)
          )
     )
     \s 
     $unit

~transformer($1,$2,$3,$4)~eixg;
```

Comment: Having 16 capture groups is a little too much don't you think? Plus all those if statements.
Isn't there a way to only have 4 capture groups. Because essentially only one case will be true at a time and each case only needs 4 capture groups.

Comment: @QasimAhmed - Sure, 16 is too much. But, I'm not making a judgement either way. In reality, `\s` and `$unit` don't need capturing, they're constants. `[^,.]` doesn't need capturing, nor does `\(?` a subset. That leaves 4 groups in 4 alternations (i.e,, 4 distinctions). Not really a job for _branch reset_ unless you want to just play with regex,